# php get last month name in local language

Tags: php, date, time, strtotime

I'd like to get the name of the last month in local language. I tried this, but I get a cryptic output:

```
setlocale(LC_TIME, 'de_DE.ISO8859-1');

echo date('%B', strtotime('-1 month')); // returns %475
echo date('F', strtotime('-1 month')); // returns April (= english)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `strftime` for localized month names:

```
echo strftime('%B', strtotime('-1 month'));
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. this gives me `M?rz` for `März` for example. How can I solve this?

Comment: Looks like a mismatch between the encoding of the month name as output by PHP (ISO8859-1) and what the browser expects. Depending on which encoding you want to use, you should either change the setlocale call to de_DE.UTF8 or change the server or your HTML source to send ISO8859-1 as the site's encoding.